# Rails how to clear database between selenium tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-rc

Rails 3 Rspec Selenium webrat

Selenium tests write to the development database.

I need a way to run rake db:reset before or after each test.

Is there a way to run rake db:reset from within an integration test?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the `database_cleaner` gem (see the documentation at https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner). Once you have it installed, you could add this to your `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: I have database_cleaner installed. Does not work or I don't know why it is not working. I think the environment gets set to test but the database that is written to is the development so maybe database_cleaner is not cleaning my development db?

Comment: Selenium tests look at Rails app not the database. I think running database_cleaner cleans the test database. I want to run a rake task from within the test to clear out the database. Any way I can do this?